# Diferença entre o desenvolvedor e o programador

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas, estrangeirismos, neologismos

Estive a ver o [StackOverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) e surgiu-me uma pergunta:

A palavra "desenvolvedor" é estrangeirismo enquanto a palavra "programador" não é? Ambas as palavras são neologismos? Seria possivel no Brasil uma palavra não ser considerada estrangeirismo enquanto em Portugal seria?

Outra pergunta interessante é: quando entrou a palavra "desenvolvedor" em uso generalizado no Brasil? Porque penso que "programador" será um termo mais antigo até nos EUA.

Em Portugal não se usa a palavra "desenvolvedor" porque já existe há décadas a palavra "programador". Gostava em especial de saber o que os "programadores"/"desenvolvedores" brasileiros com mais idade acharam quando entrou em uso a segunda palavra.

**Edit:**
[Ao escrever isto, noto que provavelmente usamos muitos estrangeirismos em Portugal que causariam estranheza aos Lusófonos de outros paises...]

Comment: No Brasil parece haver algum tipo de liberdade para uso de palavras do latim e nem chamamos isso de latinismo ou estrangeirismo, embora seja. Não importa se é uso literal ou adaptadas ao padrão de escrita do português (sufixos, prefixos, ...). Mas há casos controversos, exemplo a palavra "deletar", que embora tenha sua raiz no latim, foi absorvida no Brasil via "to delete" do Inglês. Não conheço a história da palavra "desenvolvedor" mas não me parece ter sido inglesismo.

Comment: Não sei em outros países lusófonos, mas no Brasil, há um cuidado maior, digo surgem muitas críticas, quando o termo vem do Inglês, em classificá-lo como estrangeirismo e propor palavras nativas no lugar. O mesmo não acontece com línguas asiáticas, os críticos não se incomodam com a palavra "hashi" (do japonês acho), mesmo pronunciando o H com som de R, mas muitos se incomodam com "chopstick" do inglês. Acho que há sim um exagero de estrangeirismos, muitos desnecessários, mas me parece existir também um exagero de anti-inglesismo. Por fim, ninguém chama "hashi" de pauzinhos no Brasil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Até o início da última década usávamos muito o termo `programador`, que foi "substituído" pelo termo `desenvolvedor`. A grande diferença entre eles está no conceito: enquanto `programador` destacava a habilidade e o trabalho de puramente escrever linhas de código, de programar uma máquina a executar determinadas tarefas, `desenvolvedor` surgiu para ampliar o conceito, pois criar um software é muito mais do que escrever linhas de código. Surgiu a necessidade de se pensar em aspecto de interface, usabilidade e experiência do usuário, arquitetura e projeto do software, análise de negócio e de sistema, além da codificação. `Desenvolvedor` destaca alguém que é capaz - ou responsável - por desenvolver um software, do início ao fim, em todo o seu ciclo de vida.
Acredito que isso se aplique de maneira global.

Comment: A palavra "desenvolvedor" como extensão ou sinônimo de "programador" é usada no mínimo desde o começo da década de 90, e ganhou mais uso do meio da década de 90 pra frente, isso tem no mínimo mais de 25 anos.

Comment: @Luciano sim, de fato o termo existe e é usado desde essa época, o que eu me referia é à "extinção" do termo "programador" e adesão quase que unânime ao termo "desenvolvedor". Até o final da década de 2000, era mais comum ouvir e se referir a "programador" do que "desenvolvedor". Isso mudou drasticamente na década de 2010.

Comment: Talvez precisamos de pesquisas, dados concretos, pois na minha opinião, não apenas em artigos técnicos, como nos processos de desenvolvimento, houve um aumento do uso do termo desenvolvedor no final de 90, continuou no início de 2000, mas no áuge do UP (Unified Process), voltamos a contratar programadores, e não desenvolvedores, e desde então até 2015 havia uma tendência a valorizar o nome programador, não que tenha superado desenvolvedor, apenas houve uma valorização maior do nome/função programador, do que antes.